# How can I separate number from letter using Unix regular expression?

Tags: regex, vim

How can I separate number from letter using Unix regular expression?

Example: `133748414T`

I tried this:

```
%s/^[0-9][0-9]*/^I/g
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Thanks! I want to separate 133748414 from T. and T get separated by tab

Comment: Try `%s/\v(\d)@<=(\D)@=/\t/g`

Comment: Great! this works Thank you so much

Comment: Sara,  please consider accepting/upvoting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52652396/3832970) since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
%s/\v(\d)@<=(\D)@=/\t/g
```

Here,

- `\v` - enables very magic mode
- `(\d)@<=` - the position immediately to the left of the current location should be preceded with a digit
- `(\D)@=` - the position immediately to the right of the current location should be followed with a non-digit
- `\t` - the replacement is a TAB char
- `g` - replaces all occurrences.

If you need to also add tabs between non-digits and digits, use

```
%s/\v(\d)@<=(\D)@=|(\D)@<=(\d)@=/\t/g
```

The `(\D)@<=(\d)@=` alternative branch pattern is built in a similar way as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

If it always starts with a digit:

```
%s/\ze\D/\t
```

Comment: My suggestion: `:%s/\D/\t&`